# How can I list all the files in a directory and all its sub-directories?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I list all the files in a directory and all its sub-directories?

`tree` can accomplish this job:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir
│   └── f1
└── f2

1 directory, 2 files
```

But I want files to be listed in this format:

```
dir/f1
f2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass options `-i` and `-f` to `tree`:

> tree -if

Option `-i` disables the printing of the indentation lines, option `-f` prints a path prefix for each file. This will however still list non-leaf directories.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `find` command.

```
find . -type f
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from above mentioned solution, you can list the file in directory and its subdirectory using "ls" command with  "-R" option.

ls -lR

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this listing is using printf and `ls -r`

```
printf "%s\n" "$(ls -r)"
```